# App label over-riding an earlier app label

Tags: django, namespaces

How can I assign a Django app, a label (e.g. `auth`) to over-ride an earlier application?

The `django.contrib.auth.…` modules claim the app label `auth`. I want to have that installed, but claim the `auth` label for my site's custom `auth` app.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...,
    'lorem.auth.AppConfig',
    ...,
]
```

So, the code (models, migrations, etc.) are in effect because `django.contrib.auth` is installed; but I want `lorem.auth` to get precedence for the `auth` app label.

Comment: You can use a custom AppConfig: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/  Just register django.contrib.auth under a different label.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DylanYoung, can you describe that in detail in an answer so we can examine it more?

Comment: if I get the time, but no guarantees.  It should just be a matter of subclassing the original AppConfig then overriding the app_label (and anything else you might like). Then in settings add the dotted path to that new AppConfig to your installed apps instead of the dotted path to the app.

Answer (score 0):

there is one other way you have to import any one model from auth like permission model in any of your models.py and add something like this

using meta api of django:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permissions
Permissions._meta.app_config.verbose_name = "new_name"
```

you can specify the new name like this of your existing auth name and after that you wont get any conflict in your app_name

i think this might work for you